# iced up pipe on the back of the fridge

Tags: refrigerator

I have thawed out items in the freezer, and the compressor seems to be constantly on. Turned around the fridge to find this iced-up pipe. Are those things connected and if yes, what could be the issue?

[image: iced up pipe on the back of the fridge]

Answer (score 2):

When the refrigerant pipes freeze up like that it is from being under charged in most cases but it can also be from an over charge, the good news is many systems a port can be added and the charge topped off that will have your refrigerator cycling like normal.

Prices are off topic but than will be much cheaper than a new refrigerator, the port will be less than 20$ and the few ounces of refrigerant and service call~ 150$ if an honest shop.

Unfortunately this is not normally a diy repair although I see more and more places carrying 1 lb cans of R134A a very common refrigerant. the Tap / port can be purchased online for under 5$ (BPV-31)and installed on the low side or larger pipe from the compressor then it could be topped off but I would verify the type of refrigerant (they must be the same) and the ports I get handle 3 sizes and have always worked for me but I don’t do as much small appliance repair so they might not work for everything. I just checked the model of the valve to be sure and the first link I saw was a 5 minute u-tube on how to install a bullet piercing valve so the information is out there and they sell R134A in 1 lb cans this should be more than is needed.

Now to note that I don’t know how they get away selling refrigerant to non licensed people, and there can be fines from the EPA but as R134A is what is in the canned dusters and freeze sprays that electronics techs use there are products that are designed to dump it directly to atmosphere so that may be why these small cans have become available over the last few years at least in my area.

Comment: By under charge and "refrigerant", do you mean under charged with coolant? Could it be a coolant leak?

Comment: @Natalia refrigerant is the stuff inside the pipes that gets compressed by the compressor and makes one part cool down and one part heat up

Comment: So, where did  the refrigerant disappear to?

Comment: It leaks out over time.

Comment: How do you add a refrigerant charge port to the existing plumbing without cutting open a pipe and letting all the existing refrigerant out?

Comment: I haven't seen this before. its like the pipe coming out the compressor has a partial block. Follow the ice along the pipe - see if it suddenly stops; and if there is a kink there.

Comment: Natalia, in Refridgeration equipment the “coolant” is called refrigerant, in the distant past everything was Freon R-12 , then R-21 and currently R-134A is the most popular but there are many different types R-410 is used in mini splits for example , @freeman as far as how I explained a BPB-31 has a Utube video on how two, but you clamp the valve on the pipe, there is a small loss but there is a small loss with each time a system is checked, you don’t cut the pipe it is similar to hooking up a ice maker with a saddle valve. The BPV-31 allows the system to be charged with minimal losses.

Answer (score 1):

I have the repair guy here, it turned out to be an electrical problem. The guy is Quebecois, and I am speaking to him in my broken French so I will pass the info along to the best of my ability.

He opened up the freezer to find a thick layer of ice underneath. This is a photo of it mostly thawed with a hair dryer [image]

And this is the thigie that was broken - apparently it connects the thermostat to the freezer's heating element? I did not get how it caused the pipe on the bottom of the fridge ice up.

[image]

If someone can explain this in the actual correct English below for the future Stack Exchange users, I will gladly accept your answer :)

Comment: This can stand as an answer, but if you want to know what the "thingy" is, please ask that as a stand-alone question, including all the numbers that are partially visible on it and any other lettering or other identification marks. We don't really do "Questions in the Answer box" here because there's no place for someone to put an answer that can later be found.